# Category pages blank, but shop works on WooCommerce on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

At some point, we don’t know when, category pages stopped showing anything other than the header/footer of the page. This isn’t for just one category, but all categories and sub-categories.

The main store page, and products, display fine. For example, this is a product page.
https://thesmartspacer.com/product/conference/

But, when you click on one of the categories in the breadcrumb path, you get a blank page.

Similarly, if you click on any category at:
https://thesmartspacer.com/product-category/
Nothing comes up — blank page (except header/footer).

Even categories with only products in them (e.g., no subcategories), same result:
https://thesmartspacer.com/product-category/uses-and-applications/banquet-and-events/

I’ve tried disabling all the plugins that were added at any point in recent history … or that I suspected could impact categories, including Yoast and Yoast Premium.  But, pages category and subcategory pages are still blank.

Ideas? I’m just baffled and if I cannot figure this out, I’m going to need to cleanse the site of categories so it’s functional … which is drastic, and I don’t want to go there.

Help!

Thanks!
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that others benefit from the answer that took me days to figure out...

This answer only applies to products displaying, not categories and subcategories.

We found from elegant themes that the theme template had gotten changed (I believe overwritten by a global for the default), and that there needs to be a specific WooCommerce category template that has NO body defined for the template.

So that this is documented for others, see:

[When using divi with theme templates, and WooCommerce, you must have a specific cateogry template with an empty body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr2kZ.png)

If you use templates for a theme, WooCommerce will NOT display categories unless there's a specific template set up for WooCommerce category pages that removes the body.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is showing the following error

thesmartspacer.com/:426 GET https://thesmartspacer.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

check why link is not working
thesmartspacer.com/:426 GET https://thesmartspacer.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.woff

or

Try following solution, it's on divi theme
Refer: https://divi.help/threads/ttf-module-is-slowing-down-the-page.3062/

Comment: PHP Geek, where/how were you seeing this error?